PostGIS ST_LocateAlong returns incorrect interpolated Points
Can anyone explain to me why this query returns 11 Points instead of 1? The queried 'measure' does not exist in the set of points so 'postgis' needs to do an interpolation.
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_LocateAlong(
'MULTILINESTRING M ((391304.0179999992 450205.8392000012 
290.199999999971,391303.81970000267 450205.813099999 290.2002000000066,391254.4452000037 450199.31700000167 290.25,391204.8726999983 450192.7925999984 290.29989999999816,391195.65299999714 450191.5769999996 290.30920000000333,391155.2990999967 450186.27629999816 290.34990000000107,391130.04900000244 450182.95600000024 290.37540000000445,391117.3819999993 450181.31599999964 290.3880999999965,391105.72200000286 450179.78709999844 290.399900000004,391056.1476000026 450173.2773000002 290.44980000000214,391006.5732000023 450166.7674999982 290.49980000000505,390987.0530000031 450164.2019999996 290.5194999999949,390974.19200000167 450162.50499999896 290.5323999999964,390971.1560000032 450162.0760000013 290.53549999999814,390968.0780000016 450161.6710000001 290.53859999999986,390965.03400000185 450161.30099999905 290.5417000000016,390957.0001000017 450160.249499999 290.5497999999934,390953.5600000024 450159.7960000001 290.55319999999483,390911.87900000066 450154.3359999992 290.59530000000086,390907.575000003 450153.75499999896 290.5996000000014,390894.23799999803 450152.0150000006 290.61299999999756,390890.7269999981 450151.5089999996 290.6165999999939,390887.1569999978 450151.0399999991 290.62020000000484,390883.6330000013 450150.6229999997 290.62369999999646,390857.85059999675 450147.24010000005 290.6496999999945,390854.5080000013 450146.7989999987 290.6530999999959,390808.2770999968 450140.7232000008 290.6996999999974,390804.4130000025 450140.2129999995 290.70359999999346,390797.3060000017 450139.2670000009 290.710699999996,390786.38700000197 450137.8500000015 290.7216999999946,390758.7035000026 450134.2074000016 290.74959999999555,390750.6199999973 450133.1409999989 290.7578000000067,390747.1799999997 450132.6700000018 290.7612999999983,390743.71599999815 450132.21499999985 290.76480000000447,390740.2719999999 450131.7809999995 290.7682000000059,390709.12910000235 450127.69860000163 290.79959999999846,390686.1450000033 450124.68200000003 290.82279999999446,390671.3699999973 450122.7470000014 290.8377000000037,390659.55349999666 450121.19739999995 290.8496000000014,390609.9791999981 450114.686900001 290.89949999999953,390570.2870000005 450109.47199999914 290.9395999999979,390560.4051000029 450108.17500000075 290.94950000000244,390517.41099999845 450102.51999999955 290.99280000000726,390515.59700000286 450102.25499999896 290.99469999999565,390513.72200000286 450102.0089999996 290.9965999999986,390511.8989999965 450101.7960000001 290.99839999999676,390510.8317999989 450101.6590999998 290.99950000000536,390510.11200000346 450101.563000001 291.00019999999495,390468.3369999975 450096.07499999925 291.042300000001,390461.25819999725 450095.14339999855 291.0494000000035,390459.9079999998 450094.9629999995 291.05079999999725,390457.44200000167 450094.6099999994 291.0532999999996,390454.924999997 450094.27899999917 291.0558000000019,390452.45099999756 450093.9849999994 291.05830000000424,390450.00900000334 450093.66600000113 291.06080000000657,390411.68389999866 450088.63529999927 291.0994000000064,390403.0029999986 450087.4930000007 291.1082000000024,390396.4280000031 450086.625 291.11479999999574,390393.0179999992 450086.15100000054 291.11819999999716,390392.6551999971 450086.1048000008 291.1186000000016,390392.4570999965 450086.07719999924 291.11879999999655,390374.69039999694 450083.5740999989 291.13670000000275,390362.15299999714 450081.8060000017 291.1493999999948,390342.48480000347 450079.03229999915 291.1692000000039,390100.2942999974 450044.8773000017 291.41359999999986,389736.24069999903 449980.5119000003 291.78310000000056,389401.7031000033 449902.5196999982 292.12639999999374,389099.05309999734 449817.6270999983 292.440499999997,388854.9148999974 449733.8685999997 292.69839999999385,388617.4098000005 449629.8953000009 292.9575000000041,388616.72150000185 449629.5940000005 292.95819999999367,388616.2625999972 449629.3931000009 292.95870000000286,388615.80380000174 449629.19220000133 292.9591999999975,388615.11890000105 449628.89240000024 292.9600000000064,388606.7018999979 449625.20760000125 292.9692000000068,388057.6252000034 449333.186900001 293.5905999999959,387395.69309999794 448981.24340000004 294.33980000000156,387090.0393999964 448831.45870000124 294.6799000000028,386804.58399999887 448721.2589999996 294.9857000000047,386462.741899997 448631.2039999999 295.3390000000072,385001.9195000008 448337.4893999994 296.82799999999406,384638.58410000056 448257.14649999887 297.19980000000214,384263.2783000022 448157.5295000002 297.5877999999939,383922.0446999967 448039.02230000123 297.9487999999983,383603.3224000037 447884.93400000036 298.30259999999544,383310.49589999765 447709.5236000009 298.64370000000054,383023.89130000025 447504.4978 298.99580000000424,382755.6821999997 447272.00890000165 299.35050000000047,382497.02799999714 447002.32189999893 299.724000000002,382257.72879999876 446688.3579999991 300.11840000000666,382048.3373000026 446364.69530000165 300.5037000000011,381913.120099999 446083.9222000018 300.8151000000071,381810.64859999716 445828.0359000005 301.0905000000057,381720.62650000304 445527.8055000007 301.4036999999953,381650.45369999856 445227.7798999995 301.7115999999951,381602.93190000206 444926.7265999988 302.0161999999982,381374.7028999999 441490.6794000007 305.4573999999993,381357.2776999995 441281.5124000013 305.6671999999962,381331.4759000018 441093.3808000013 305.85689999999886,381273.94409999996 440866.03810000047 306.09130000000005,381192.1789999977 440651.7248999998 306.32050000000163,381100.16870000213 440464.85709999874 306.5286000000051,380969.7211000025 440267.13639999926 306.7652999999991,380820.2511000037 440092.3354000002 306.99520000000484,380678.66049999744 439951.92449999973 307.19439999999304,380154.7648999989 439553.6748000011 307.8521000000037,380040.99870000035 439467.1928000003 307.99490000000515,379925.2670999989 439379.2318999991 308.14010000000417,379924.6666999981 439378.7756000012 308.1408999999985,379924.2551999986 439378.46290000156 308.14139999999315,379923.84380000085 439378.15019999817 308.14190000000235,379923.2264999971 439377.6810000017 308.1426999999967,379884.59149999917 439348.3167999983 308.1912000000011,379790.5357000008 439252.6449000016 308.3252999999968,379707.2884000018 439131.7932000011 308.4719000000041,379647.4650000036 439003.04580000043 308.61380000000645,379600.745099999 438865.2602000013 308.7592000000004,379577.494099997 438729.42550000176 308.896900000007,379575.94849999994 438602.0945999995 309.0240999999951,379591.317900002 438490.80959999934 309.13640000000305,379624.71589999646 438361.2204999998 309.2700999999943,379667.80680000037 438255.2281999998 309.3845000000001,379728.4499000013 438146.9479999989 309.5084999999963,379728.80690000206 438146.31069999933 309.5092000000004,379729.0447999984 438145.8858000003 309.50969999999506,379729.2827000022 438145.4609999992 309.51020000000426,379729.6396000013 438144.8236999996 309.51089999999385,379732.52109999955 438139.67870000005 309.5167999999976,379803.1770000011 438034.02369999886 309.6438000000053,379908.87049999833 437906.66110000014 309.80920000000333,379970.565700002 437794.09259999916 309.9375,380005.97890000045 437694.3995999992 310.04320000000007,380048.4065999985 437556.42020000145 310.1875,380049.8095000014 437551.85280000046 310.19220000000496,380050.76900000125 437548.7289999984 310.19550000000163,380050.816200003 437548.5346999988 310.19839999999385,380055.0539999977 437531.1020000018 310.45870000000286,380055.1049999967 437530.89499999955 310.4618000000046,380060.7721000016 437507.9849999994 310.8040999999939,380062.876000002 437499.46599999815 310.9314000000013,380063.9469999969 437495.09699999914 310.99670000000333,380066.81099999696 437483.2419999987 311.1735999999946,380067.248999998 437481.37900000066 311.2014000000054,380070.4450000003 437467.4450000003 311.40869999999995,380070.4549999982 437467.3999999985 311.4094000000041,380071.27859999985 437463.51669999957 311.4670000000042),(380071.27859999985 437463.51669999957 310.19550000000163,380072.17180000246 437459.30519999936 310.37690000000293,380073.94200000167 437450.9360000007 310.7375000000029,380074.02899999917 437450.4979999997 310.75629999999364,380076.28400000185 437438.4539999999 311.27270000000135,380077.08349999785 437433.9134999998 311.4670000000042),(380077.08349999785 437433.9134999998 310.19550000000163,380077.10599999875 437433.78599999845 310.19740000000456,380078.55799999833 437424.73699999973 310.33120000000054,380079.5949999988 437417.5720000006 310.4369000000006,380080.5530000031 437410.03130000085 310.54790000000503,380080.7349999994 437408.5789999999 310.56930000000284,380081.4299999997 437402.1570000015 310.66359999999986,380082.17099999636 437393.88800000027 310.784799999994,380082.54599999636 437388.3999999985 310.8652000000002,380083.16600000113 437376.05700000003 311.04559999999765,380083.188000001 437375.375 311.05560000000696,380083.3049999997 437366.34099999815 311.1875,380083.2870000005 437359.9479999989 311.2808999999979,380083.11599999666 437351.9609999992 311.3975000000064,380082.927199997 437347.2069000006 311.4670000000042),(380082.927199997 437347.2069000006 310.19550000000163,380082.92099999636 437347.0520000011 310.19719999999506,380082.4750000015 437339.2879999988 310.2844000000041,380082.0150000006 437333.19099999964 310.35289999999804,380081.29599999636 437325.46499999985 310.4398999999976,380080.77099999785 437320.7960000001 310.49259999999776,380079.4949999973 437311.0639999993 310.60259999999835,380079.3874000013 437310.33309999853 310.6107999999949,380078.74599999934 437306.0480000004 310.6594000000041,380077.58200000226 437299.1279999986 310.7381000000023,380076.5860000029 437293.76399999857 310.799199999994,380075.12900000066 437286.64400000125 310.88069999999425,380073.5850000009 437279.7470000014 310.95990000000165,380071.6950000003 437271.9820000008 311.0494000000035,380070.5850000009 437267.72100000083 311.09880000000703,380069.4699999988 437263.75400000066 311.1450000000041,380068.80390000343 437261.5073999986 311.17119999999704,380066.0530000031 437252.2490000017 311.2795000000042,380065.4799999967 437250.4600000009 311.3006000000023,380060.87900000066 437236.9820000008 311.46020000000135,380060.72399999946 437236.5489999987 311.4652999999962,380060.67130000144 437236.40940000117 311.4670000000042),(380060.67130000144 437236.40940000117 310.19550000000163,380058.813000001 437231.48999999836 310.27999999999884,380056.8589999974 437226.4979999997 310.3660999999993,380054.32900000364 437220.35500000045 310.4728999999934,380051.8127000034 437214.52589999884 310.5749000000069,380050.81400000304 437212.21499999985 310.61539999999513,380048.825000003 437207.8539999984 310.6923999999999,380044.6770000011 437199.1970000006 310.8466999999946,380042.4139999971 437194.69099999964 310.9277000000002,380038.83200000226 437187.8509999998 311.0518000000011,380037.3060000017 437185.05999999866 311.10289999999804,380031.70799999684 437175.1979999989 311.2850999999937,380030.8219999969 437173.6979999989 311.3130999999994,380028.6904999986 437170.2388000004 311.3784000000014,380025.8280000016 437165.5949999988 311.46600000000035,380025.79580000043 437165.5443999991 311.4670000000042),(380025.79580000043 437165.5443999991 310.19550000000163,380023.4130000025 437161.80099999905 310.24589999999444,380020.1279999986 437156.8299999982 310.31350000000384,380016.96599999815 437152.19299999997 310.37729999999283,380013.5850000009 437147.40900000185 310.44379999999364,380008.95600000024 437141.09699999914 310.5326999999961,380004.67599999905 437135.46599999815 310.61299999999756,380001.54900000244 437131.52600000054 310.670100000003,379999.8496999964 437129.4433000013 310.7005999999965,379996.36900000274 437125.1770000011 310.7630999999965,379994.25599999726 437122.65399999917 310.80049999999756,379989.3980000019 437117.08199999854 310.88439999999537,379985.8720000014 437113.1810000017 310.94409999999334,379982.2100000009 437109.21599999815 311.00539999999455,379979.96400000155 437106.81700000167 311.0427000000054,379978.97399999946 437105.7749999985 311.05899999999383,379974.18599999696 437100.8929999992 311.13670000000275,379972.2880000025 437099.00400000066 311.16710000000603,379966.81599999964 437093.69299999997 311.2537000000011,379965.8778000027 437092.80779999867 311.2682999999961,379964.54100000113 437091.5450000018 311.28919999999925,379956.63599999994 437084.3049999997 311.4109000000026,379952.9504000023 437081.01740000024 311.4670000000042),(379952.9504000023 437081.01740000024 310.19550000000163,379952.376000002 437080.50499999896 310.2057000000059,379946.2299999967 437075.16099999845 310.3139999999985,379945.00400000066 437074.12000000104 310.3353999999963,379936.0799999982 437066.6700000018 310.49000000000524,379935.825000003 437066.4609999992 310.49439999999595,379928.008100003 437060.1832999997 310.6276999999973,379925.59099999815 437058.2410000004 310.6689999999944,379921.8189999983 437055.26099999994 310.7329000000027,379912.92400000244 437048.34099999815 310.88270000000193,379912.8360000029 437048.2729999982 310.8842000000004,379901.8849999979 437039.9230000004 311.0673999999999,379900.95899999887 437039.22199999914 311.0828000000038,379888.34619999677 437029.74159999937 311.2926000000007,379886.6969999969 437028.5009999983 311.3200999999972,379877.8601000011 437021.8685000017 311.4670000000042),(379877.8601000011 437021.8685000017 310.19550000000163,379851.5600000024 437002.12900000066 310.3790000000008,379848.3572999984 436999.72679999843 310.40140000000247,379844.45419999957 436996.7974999994 310.4285999999993,379840.8439999968 436994.0879999995 310.45380000000296,379840.5125999972 436993.8392000012 310.4560999999958,379836.33569999784 436990.70380000025 310.4853000000003,379818.3049999997 436977.16899999976 310.6110999999946,379808.36779999733 436969.71279999986 310.68039999999746,379807.5900000036 436969.1279999986 310.68589999999676,379798.4650000036 436962.2740000002 310.74959999999555,379771.90200000256 436942.3269999996 310.9349999999977,379768.38599999994 436939.6884999983 310.9594999999972,379757.45799999684 436931.4840000011 311.03579999999783,379754.2260000035 436929.0709999986 311.05830000000424,379747.7829999998 436924.2170000002 311.1033000000025,379742.9629999995 436920.59800000116 311.13700000000244,379728.40129999816 436909.6682000011 311.23859999999695,379695.67080000043 436885.09899999946 311.4670000000042),(379695.67080000043 436885.09899999946 310.19550000000163,379688.41380000114 436879.65150000155 310.25680000000284,379648.4262999967 436849.63489999995 310.594299999997,379645.15200000256 436847.17599999905 310.622000000003,379640.44099999964 436843.53599999845 310.6621000000014,379635.7349999994 436840.00499999896 310.7019,379630.9219999984 436836.4990000017 310.7421000000031,379608.43670000136 436819.6229999997 310.93189999999595,379568.4479999989 436789.6079999991 311.2694000000047,379545.12900000066 436772.1039999984 311.46630000000005,379545.04129999876 436772.03819999844 311.4670000000042),(379545.04129999876 436772.03819999844 310.19550000000163,379528.45639999956 436759.5967000015 310.44340000000375,379505.188000001 436742.13899999857 310.79129999999714,379505.11200000346 436742.08199999854 310.7924000000057,379488.5196999982 436729.5128000006 311.04129999999714,379479.25900000334 436722.49599999934 311.1802000000025,379465.95799999684 436712.3539999984 311.38030000000435,379463.2739999965 436710.2969999984 311.4207000000024,379460.2277000025 436707.90579999983 311.4670000000042),(379460.2277000025 436707.90579999983 310.19550000000163,379459.34899999946 436707.21599999815 310.20530000000144,379451.9120000005 436701.3280000016 310.28859999999986,379448.9452999979 436698.9571999982 310.3220000000001,379445.22100000083 436695.9789999984 310.36380000000645,379441.875 436693.29100000113 310.4015000000072,379441.53400000185 436693.01399999857 310.4054000000033,379430.0450000018 436683.4439999983 310.5366999999969,379421.6819999963 436676.3819999993 310.6328000000067,379421.5780000016 436676.29300000146 310.63400000000547,379417.60599999875 436672.7199999988 310.68090000000666,379410.84920000285 436666.59160000086 310.7609999999986,379409.9839999974 436665.8060000017 310.77129999999306,379401.25900000334 
436657.80900000036 310.87519999999495,379388.37099999934 436645.8359999992 311.02969999999914,379385.0380000025 436642.7019999996 311.06990000000224,379381.7199999988 436639.55799999833 311.1100000000006,379378.4120000005 436636.3999999985 311.1502000000037,379374.3175999969 436632.4556999989 311.20010000000184,379365.62099999934 436624.0760000013 311.3061000000016,379360.9280000031 436619.5080000013 311.36359999999695,379357.8549999967 436616.37099999934 311.4021999999968,379353.36200000346 436611.7520000003 311.45879999999306,379352.8527000025 436611.22309999913 311.465200000006,379352.71400000155 436611.0789999999 311.4670000000042))'::geometry
    ,310.916000));

Response:
"MULTIPOINT M (380062.6214826414 437500.49657816015 310.916,380074.7263731604 437446.7733160337 310.916,380082.7205897982 437384.9242549878 310.916,380074.44082828355 437283.56995833444 310.916,380042.7408777754 437195.3418666664 310.916,379987.53164154233 437115.0171490786 310.916,379910.9351168143 437046.8236004353 310.916,379774.6242060433 436944.3711909379 310.916,379610.32034736633 436821.03674288676 310.916,379496.87251313875 436735.84032414586 310.916,379397.85556699225 436654.647198058 310.916)"


"[...] so 'postgis' needs to do an interpolation." - that's the idea.

There's 11 parts, and 11 places where the value transitions below to above measure 310.916. Why do you expect only a single-part output?

@Richard    If the correct is the one in your response please put it as an answer so other users can benefit from it .

If you expect only one point, your line measures must not repeat.  If you are able to adjust the measure values of your lines, you could make them contiguous by running st_addmeasure(geom, st_m(st_startpoint(geom)), st_m(st_endpoint(geom))).  If you can't modify the measure values, you could use LIMIT 1 to return only 1 point.  To keep the point location consistent, you could use the centroid of the multipoint and snap it to the line...

If you look at the WKT in a text editor, and you reformat it to have one vertex per line, it becomes pretty obvious where the interpolated values are calculated:
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_LocateAlong(
'MULTILINESTRING M ((
        391304.0179999992 450205.8392000012 290.199999999971,
        391303.81970000267 450205.813099999 290.2002000000066,
        391254.4452000037 450199.31700000167 290.25,
        391204.8726999983 450192.7925999984 290.29989999999816,
        391195.65299999714 450191.5769999996 290.30920000000333,
        391155.2990999967 450186.27629999816 290.34990000000107,
        391130.04900000244 450182.95600000024 290.37540000000445,
        391117.3819999993 450181.31599999964 290.3880999999965,
        391105.72200000286 450179.78709999844 290.399900000004,
        391056.1476000026 450173.2773000002 290.44980000000214,
        391006.5732000023 450166.7674999982 290.49980000000505,
        390987.0530000031 450164.2019999996 290.5194999999949,
        390974.19200000167 450162.50499999896 290.5323999999964,
        390971.1560000032 450162.0760000013 290.53549999999814,
        390968.0780000016 450161.6710000001 290.53859999999986,
        390965.03400000185 450161.30099999905 290.5417000000016,
        390957.0001000017 450160.249499999 290.5497999999934,
        390953.5600000024 450159.7960000001 290.55319999999483,
        390911.87900000066 450154.3359999992 290.59530000000086,
        390907.575000003 450153.75499999896 290.5996000000014,
        390894.23799999803 450152.0150000006 290.61299999999756,
        390890.7269999981 450151.5089999996 290.6165999999939,
        390887.1569999978 450151.0399999991 290.62020000000484,
        390883.6330000013 450150.6229999997 290.62369999999646,
        390857.85059999675 450147.24010000005 290.6496999999945,
        390854.5080000013 450146.7989999987 290.6530999999959,
        390808.2770999968 450140.7232000008 290.6996999999974,
        390804.4130000025 450140.2129999995 290.70359999999346,
        390797.3060000017 450139.2670000009 290.710699999996,
        390786.38700000197 450137.8500000015 290.7216999999946,
        390758.7035000026 450134.2074000016 290.74959999999555,
        390750.6199999973 450133.1409999989 290.7578000000067,
        390747.1799999997 450132.6700000018 290.7612999999983,
        390743.71599999815 450132.21499999985 290.76480000000447,
        390740.2719999999 450131.7809999995 290.7682000000059,
        390709.12910000235 450127.69860000163 290.79959999999846,
        390686.1450000033 450124.68200000003 290.82279999999446,
        390671.3699999973 450122.7470000014 290.8377000000037,
        390659.55349999666 450121.19739999995 290.8496000000014,
        390609.9791999981 450114.686900001 290.89949999999953,
        390570.2870000005 450109.47199999914 290.9395999999979,
        390560.4051000029 450108.17500000075 290.94950000000244,
        390517.41099999845 450102.51999999955 290.99280000000726,
        390515.59700000286 450102.25499999896 290.99469999999565,
        390513.72200000286 450102.0089999996 290.9965999999986,
        390511.8989999965 450101.7960000001 290.99839999999676,
        390510.8317999989 450101.6590999998 290.99950000000536,
        390510.11200000346 450101.563000001 291.00019999999495,
        390468.3369999975 450096.07499999925 291.042300000001,
        390461.25819999725 450095.14339999855 291.0494000000035,
        390459.9079999998 450094.9629999995 291.05079999999725,
        390457.44200000167 450094.6099999994 291.0532999999996,
        390454.924999997 450094.27899999917 291.0558000000019,
        390452.45099999756 450093.9849999994 291.05830000000424,
        390450.00900000334 450093.66600000113 291.06080000000657,
        390411.68389999866 450088.63529999927 291.0994000000064,
        390403.0029999986 450087.4930000007 291.1082000000024,
        390396.4280000031 450086.625 291.11479999999574,
        390393.0179999992 450086.15100000054 291.11819999999716,
        390392.6551999971 450086.1048000008 291.1186000000016,
        390392.4570999965 450086.07719999924 291.11879999999655,
        390374.69039999694 450083.5740999989 291.13670000000275,
        390362.15299999714 450081.8060000017 291.1493999999948,
        390342.48480000347 450079.03229999915 291.1692000000039,
        390100.2942999974 450044.8773000017 291.41359999999986,
        389736.24069999903 449980.5119000003 291.78310000000056,
        389401.7031000033 449902.5196999982 292.12639999999374,
        389099.05309999734 449817.6270999983 292.440499999997,
        388854.9148999974 449733.8685999997 292.69839999999385,
        388617.4098000005 449629.8953000009 292.9575000000041,
        388616.72150000185 449629.5940000005 292.95819999999367,
        388616.2625999972 449629.3931000009 292.95870000000286,
        388615.80380000174 449629.19220000133 292.9591999999975,
        388615.11890000105 449628.89240000024 292.9600000000064,
        388606.7018999979 449625.20760000125 292.9692000000068,
        388057.6252000034 449333.186900001 293.5905999999959,
        387395.69309999794 448981.24340000004 294.33980000000156,
        387090.0393999964 448831.45870000124 294.6799000000028,
        386804.58399999887 448721.2589999996 294.9857000000047,
        386462.741899997 448631.2039999999 295.3390000000072,
        385001.9195000008 448337.4893999994 296.82799999999406,
        384638.58410000056 448257.14649999887 297.19980000000214,
        384263.2783000022 448157.5295000002 297.5877999999939,
        383922.0446999967 448039.02230000123 297.9487999999983,
        383603.3224000037 447884.93400000036 298.30259999999544,
        383310.49589999765 447709.5236000009 298.64370000000054,
        383023.89130000025 447504.4978 298.99580000000424,
        382755.6821999997 447272.00890000165 299.35050000000047,
        382497.02799999714 447002.32189999893 299.724000000002,
        382257.72879999876 446688.3579999991 300.11840000000666,
        382048.3373000026 446364.69530000165 300.5037000000011,
        381913.120099999 446083.9222000018 300.8151000000071,
        381810.64859999716 445828.0359000005 301.0905000000057,
        381720.62650000304 445527.8055000007 301.4036999999953,
        381650.45369999856 445227.7798999995 301.7115999999951,
        381602.93190000206 444926.7265999988 302.0161999999982,
        381374.7028999999 441490.6794000007 305.4573999999993,
        381357.2776999995 441281.5124000013 305.6671999999962,
        381331.4759000018 441093.3808000013 305.85689999999886,
        381273.94409999996 440866.03810000047 306.09130000000005,
        381192.1789999977 440651.7248999998 306.32050000000163,
        381100.16870000213 440464.85709999874 306.5286000000051,
        380969.7211000025 440267.13639999926 306.7652999999991,
        380820.2511000037 440092.3354000002 306.99520000000484,
        380678.66049999744 439951.92449999973 307.19439999999304,
        380154.7648999989 439553.6748000011 307.8521000000037,
        380040.99870000035 439467.1928000003 307.99490000000515,
        379925.2670999989 439379.2318999991 308.14010000000417,
        379924.6666999981 439378.7756000012 308.1408999999985,
        379924.2551999986 439378.46290000156 308.14139999999315,
        379923.84380000085 439378.15019999817 308.14190000000235,
        379923.2264999971 439377.6810000017 308.1426999999967,
        379884.59149999917 439348.3167999983 308.1912000000011,
        379790.5357000008 439252.6449000016 308.3252999999968,
        379707.2884000018 439131.7932000011 308.4719000000041,
        379647.4650000036 439003.04580000043 308.61380000000645,
        379600.745099999 438865.2602000013 308.7592000000004,
        379577.494099997 438729.42550000176 308.896900000007,
        379575.94849999994 438602.0945999995 309.0240999999951,
        379591.317900002 438490.80959999934 309.13640000000305,
        379624.71589999646 438361.2204999998 309.2700999999943,
        379667.80680000037 438255.2281999998 309.3845000000001,
        379728.4499000013 438146.9479999989 309.5084999999963,
        379728.80690000206 438146.31069999933 309.5092000000004,
        379729.0447999984 438145.8858000003 309.50969999999506,
        379729.2827000022 438145.4609999992 309.51020000000426,
        379729.6396000013 438144.8236999996 309.51089999999385,
        379732.52109999955 438139.67870000005 309.5167999999976,
        379803.1770000011 438034.02369999886 309.6438000000053,
        379908.87049999833 437906.66110000014 309.80920000000333,
        379970.565700002 437794.09259999916 309.9375,
        380005.97890000045 437694.3995999992 310.04320000000007,
        380048.4065999985 437556.42020000145 310.1875,
        380049.8095000014 437551.85280000046 310.19220000000496,
        380050.76900000125 437548.7289999984 310.19550000000163,
        380050.816200003 437548.5346999988 310.19839999999385,
        380055.0539999977 437531.1020000018 310.45870000000286,
        380055.1049999967 437530.89499999955 310.4618000000046,
        380060.7721000016 437507.9849999994 310.8040999999939,
XX
        380062.876000002 437499.46599999815 310.9314000000013,
        380063.9469999969 437495.09699999914 310.99670000000333,
        380066.81099999696 437483.2419999987 311.1735999999946,
        380067.248999998 437481.37900000066 311.2014000000054,
        380070.4450000003 437467.4450000003 311.40869999999995,
        380070.4549999982 437467.3999999985 311.4094000000041,
        380071.27859999985 437463.51669999957 311.4670000000042),
    (380071.27859999985 437463.51669999957 310.19550000000163,
        380072.17180000246 437459.30519999936 310.37690000000293,
        380073.94200000167 437450.9360000007 310.7375000000029,
        380074.02899999917 437450.4979999997 310.75629999999364,
XX
        380076.28400000185 437438.4539999999 311.27270000000135,
        380077.08349999785 437433.9134999998 311.4670000000042),
    (380077.08349999785 437433.9134999998 310.19550000000163,
        380077.10599999875 437433.78599999845 310.19740000000456,
        380078.55799999833 437424.73699999973 310.33120000000054,
        380079.5949999988 437417.5720000006 310.4369000000006,
        380080.5530000031 437410.03130000085 310.54790000000503,
        380080.7349999994 437408.5789999999 310.56930000000284,
        380081.4299999997 437402.1570000015 310.66359999999986,
        380082.17099999636 437393.88800000027 310.784799999994,
        380082.54599999636 437388.3999999985 310.8652000000002,
XX
        380083.16600000113 437376.05700000003 311.04559999999765,
        380083.188000001 437375.375 311.05560000000696,
        380083.3049999997 437366.34099999815 311.1875,
        380083.2870000005 437359.9479999989 311.2808999999979,
        380083.11599999666 437351.9609999992 311.3975000000064,
        380082.927199997 437347.2069000006 311.4670000000042),
    (380082.927199997 437347.2069000006 310.19550000000163,
        380082.92099999636 437347.0520000011 310.19719999999506,
        380082.4750000015 437339.2879999988 310.2844000000041,
        380082.0150000006 437333.19099999964 310.35289999999804,
        380081.29599999636 437325.46499999985 310.4398999999976,
        380080.77099999785 437320.7960000001 310.49259999999776,
        380079.4949999973 437311.0639999993 310.60259999999835,
        380079.3874000013 437310.33309999853 310.6107999999949,
        380078.74599999934 437306.0480000004 310.6594000000041,
        380077.58200000226 437299.1279999986 310.7381000000023,
        380076.5860000029 437293.76399999857 310.799199999994,
        380075.12900000066 437286.64400000125 310.88069999999425,
XX
        380073.5850000009 437279.7470000014 310.95990000000165,
        380071.6950000003 437271.9820000008 311.0494000000035,
        380070.5850000009 437267.72100000083 311.09880000000703,
        380069.4699999988 437263.75400000066 311.1450000000041,
        380068.80390000343 437261.5073999986 311.17119999999704,
        380066.0530000031 437252.2490000017 311.2795000000042,
        380065.4799999967 437250.4600000009 311.3006000000023,
        380060.87900000066 437236.9820000008 311.46020000000135,
        380060.72399999946 437236.5489999987 311.4652999999962,
        380060.67130000144 437236.40940000117 311.4670000000042),
    (380060.67130000144 437236.40940000117 310.19550000000163,
        380058.813000001 437231.48999999836 310.27999999999884,
        380056.8589999974 437226.4979999997 310.3660999999993,
        380054.32900000364 437220.35500000045 310.4728999999934,
        380051.8127000034 437214.52589999884 310.5749000000069,
        380050.81400000304 437212.21499999985 310.61539999999513,
        380048.825000003 437207.8539999984 310.6923999999999,
        380044.6770000011 437199.1970000006 310.8466999999946,
XX
        380042.4139999971 437194.69099999964 310.9277000000002,
        380038.83200000226 437187.8509999998 311.0518000000011,
        380037.3060000017 437185.05999999866 311.10289999999804,
        380031.70799999684 437175.1979999989 311.2850999999937,
        380030.8219999969 437173.6979999989 311.3130999999994,
        380028.6904999986 437170.2388000004 311.3784000000014,
        380025.8280000016 437165.5949999988 311.46600000000035,
        380025.79580000043 437165.5443999991 311.4670000000042),
    (380025.79580000043 437165.5443999991 310.19550000000163,
        380023.4130000025 437161.80099999905 310.24589999999444,
        380020.1279999986 437156.8299999982 310.31350000000384,
        380016.96599999815 437152.19299999997 310.37729999999283,
        380013.5850000009 437147.40900000185 310.44379999999364,
        380008.95600000024 437141.09699999914 310.5326999999961,
        380004.67599999905 437135.46599999815 310.61299999999756,
        380001.54900000244 437131.52600000054 310.670100000003,
        379999.8496999964 437129.4433000013 310.7005999999965,
        379996.36900000274 437125.1770000011 310.7630999999965,
        379994.25599999726 437122.65399999917 310.80049999999756,
        379989.3980000019 437117.08199999854 310.88439999999537,
XX
        379985.8720000014 437113.1810000017 310.94409999999334,
        379982.2100000009 437109.21599999815 311.00539999999455,
        379979.96400000155 437106.81700000167 311.0427000000054,
        379978.97399999946 437105.7749999985 311.05899999999383,
        379974.18599999696 437100.8929999992 311.13670000000275,
        379972.2880000025 437099.00400000066 311.16710000000603,
        379966.81599999964 437093.69299999997 311.2537000000011,
        379965.8778000027 437092.80779999867 311.2682999999961,
        379964.54100000113 437091.5450000018 311.28919999999925,
        379956.63599999994 437084.3049999997 311.4109000000026,
        379952.9504000023 437081.01740000024 311.4670000000042),
    (379952.9504000023 437081.01740000024 310.19550000000163,
        379952.376000002 437080.50499999896 310.2057000000059,
        379946.2299999967 437075.16099999845 310.3139999999985,
        379945.00400000066 437074.12000000104 310.3353999999963,
        379936.0799999982 437066.6700000018 310.49000000000524,
        379935.825000003 437066.4609999992 310.49439999999595,
        379928.008100003 437060.1832999997 310.6276999999973,
        379925.59099999815 437058.2410000004 310.6689999999944,
        379921.8189999983 437055.26099999994 310.7329000000027,
        379912.92400000244 437048.34099999815 310.88270000000193,
        379912.8360000029 437048.2729999982 310.8842000000004,
XX
        379901.8849999979 437039.9230000004 311.0673999999999,
        379900.95899999887 437039.22199999914 311.0828000000038,
        379888.34619999677 437029.74159999937 311.2926000000007,
        379886.6969999969 437028.5009999983 311.3200999999972,
        379877.8601000011 437021.8685000017 311.4670000000042),
    (379877.8601000011 437021.8685000017 310.19550000000163,
        379851.5600000024 437002.12900000066 310.3790000000008,
        379848.3572999984 436999.72679999843 310.40140000000247,
        379844.45419999957 436996.7974999994 310.4285999999993,
        379840.8439999968 436994.0879999995 310.45380000000296,
        379840.5125999972 436993.8392000012 310.4560999999958,
        379836.33569999784 436990.70380000025 310.4853000000003,
        379818.3049999997 436977.16899999976 310.6110999999946,
        379808.36779999733 436969.71279999986 310.68039999999746,
        379807.5900000036 436969.1279999986 310.68589999999676,
        379798.4650000036 436962.2740000002 310.74959999999555,
XX
        379771.90200000256 436942.3269999996 310.9349999999977,
        379768.38599999994 436939.6884999983 310.9594999999972,
        379757.45799999684 436931.4840000011 311.03579999999783,
        379754.2260000035 436929.0709999986 311.05830000000424,
        379747.7829999998 436924.2170000002 311.1033000000025,
        379742.9629999995 436920.59800000116 311.13700000000244,
        379728.40129999816 436909.6682000011 311.23859999999695,
        379695.67080000043 436885.09899999946 311.4670000000042),
    (379695.67080000043 436885.09899999946 310.19550000000163,
        379688.41380000114 436879.65150000155 310.25680000000284,
        379648.4262999967 436849.63489999995 310.594299999997,
        379645.15200000256 436847.17599999905 310.622000000003,
        379640.44099999964 436843.53599999845 310.6621000000014,
        379635.7349999994 436840.00499999896 310.7019,
        379630.9219999984 436836.4990000017 310.7421000000031,
XX
        379608.43670000136 436819.6229999997 310.93189999999595,
        379568.4479999989 436789.6079999991 311.2694000000047,
        379545.12900000066 436772.1039999984 311.46630000000005,
        379545.04129999876 436772.03819999844 311.4670000000042),
    (379545.04129999876 436772.03819999844 310.19550000000163,
        379528.45639999956 436759.5967000015 310.44340000000375,
        379505.188000001 436742.13899999857 310.79129999999714,
        379505.11200000346 436742.08199999854 310.7924000000057,
XX
        379488.5196999982 436729.5128000006 311.04129999999714,
        379479.25900000334 436722.49599999934 311.1802000000025,
        379465.95799999684 436712.3539999984 311.38030000000435,
        379463.2739999965 436710.2969999984 311.4207000000024,
        379460.2277000025 436707.90579999983 311.4670000000042),
    (379460.2277000025 436707.90579999983 310.19550000000163,
        379459.34899999946 436707.21599999815 310.20530000000144,
        379451.9120000005 436701.3280000016 310.28859999999986,
        379448.9452999979 436698.9571999982 310.3220000000001,
        379445.22100000083 436695.9789999984 310.36380000000645,
        379441.875 436693.29100000113 310.4015000000072,
        379441.53400000185 436693.01399999857 310.4054000000033,
        379430.0450000018 436683.4439999983 310.5366999999969,
        379421.6819999963 436676.3819999993 310.6328000000067,
        379421.5780000016 436676.29300000146 310.63400000000547,
        379417.60599999875 436672.7199999988 310.68090000000666,
        379410.84920000285 436666.59160000086 310.7609999999986,
        379409.9839999974 436665.8060000017 310.77129999999306,
        379401.25900000334 436657.80900000036 310.87519999999495,
XX
        379388.37099999934 436645.8359999992 311.02969999999914,
        379385.0380000025 436642.7019999996 311.06990000000224,
        379381.7199999988 436639.55799999833 311.1100000000006,
        379378.4120000005 436636.3999999985 311.1502000000037,
        379374.3175999969 436632.4556999989 311.20010000000184,
        379365.62099999934 436624.0760000013 311.3061000000016,
        379360.9280000031 436619.5080000013 311.36359999999695,
        379357.8549999967 436616.37099999934 311.4021999999968,
        379353.36200000346 436611.7520000003 311.45879999999306,
        379352.8527000025 436611.22309999913 311.465200000006,
        379352.71400000155 436611.0789999999 311.4670000000042))'::geometry
    ,310.916000));

Eleven parts, each with a transition over the interpolated value, when interpolated, results in a multipart point feature with eleven points.

Here's a simpler example of the behaviour:
SELECT ST_AsText(
  ST_LocateAlong(
    'MULTILINESTRINGM( ( 0  0  0, 2  2  2)
                      ,(-1  0 -1, 1  0  1)
                      ,( 8  8  8, 9  9  9))'::geometry,
    1.0 ));




st_astext




MULTIPOINT M ((1 1 1),(1 0 1))




The first line doesn't have a vertex with M of 1.0, but it does cross the target, so you get an interpolated location on that line.
The second line has a vertex on there, so you get that point.
The third one doesn't cross that M, so it doesn't return anything.

To debug your case, you can explode the geometry with ST_Dump() and ST_DumpPoints(), then use distinct on to pick out one point right before, and another one right after the target measure.
That will highlight what @Vince already suggested: you have a set of 11 lines, and each of them passes over that M coord. When you ST_LocateAlong() the measure, it gives you an interpolated location on each of the 11 lines.
Here's a demo at db<>fiddle:
select distinct on (line_number, st_m(dump2.geom) > 310.916000) 
       line_number, vertex_number, st_astext(dump2.geom)
from st_dump('MULTILINESTRING M ((391304.017....311.4670000000042))'::geometry)
       with ordinality as dump1(path,geom,line_number)
cross join lateral st_dumppoints(dump1.geom) 
       with ordinality as dump2(path,geom,vertex_number)
order by line_number
        ,st_m(dump2.geom)>310.916000
        ,abs(310.916000-st_m(dump2.geom));

This order by instructs the distinct on to get one  point for each line that has M higher than your target, one lower than your target, and from among the ones available in either group, get the one that's closest to the target M.



line_number
vertex_number
st_astext




1
139
POINT M (380060.7721000016 437507.9849999994 310.8040999999939)


1
140
POINT M (380062.876000002 437499.46599999815 310.9314000000013)


2
4
POINT M (380074.02899999917 437450.4979999997 310.75629999999364)


2
5
POINT M (380076.28400000185 437438.4539999999 311.27270000000135)


3
9
POINT M (380082.54599999636 437388.3999999985 310.8652000000002)


3
10
POINT M (380083.16600000113 437376.05700000003 311.04559999999765)


4
12
POINT M (380075.12900000066 437286.64400000125 310.88069999999425)


4
13
POINT M (380073.5850000009 437279.7470000014 310.95990000000165)


5
8
POINT M (380044.6770000011 437199.1970000006 310.8466999999946)


5
9
POINT M (380042.4139999971 437194.69099999964 310.9277000000002)


6
12
POINT M (379989.3980000019 437117.08199999854 310.88439999999537)


6
13
POINT M (379985.8720000014 437113.1810000017 310.94409999999334)


7
11
POINT M (379912.8360000029 437048.2729999982 310.8842000000004)


7
12
POINT M (379901.8849999979 437039.9230000004 311.0673999999999)


8
11
POINT M (379798.4650000036 436962.2740000002 310.74959999999555)


8
12
POINT M (379771.90200000256 436942.3269999996 310.9349999999977)


9
7
POINT M (379630.9219999984 436836.4990000017 310.7421000000031)


9
8
POINT M (379608.43670000136 436819.6229999997 310.93189999999595)


10
4
POINT M (379505.11200000346 436742.08199999854 310.7924000000057)


10
5
POINT M (379488.5196999982 436729.5128000006 311.04129999999714)


11
14
POINT M (379401.25900000334 436657.80900000036 310.87519999999495)


11
15
POINT M (379388.37099999934 436645.8359999992 311.02969999999914)



I'm only using with ordinality to get ordinal numbers directly, instead of taking them out of the path, which will be an array.
You can swap out the cross join lateral for a single comma , since the dependency of the set-returning function calls is clear.
To debug more than one geometry this way, you can add its identifier as the first field inside distinct on(), right after distinct on() and in the order by lists.
